# Embedding Raw XML from external file into a Typescript file

Tags: xml, typescript, embedding

I'm trying to embed XML within a Typescript file, creating the effect of:

```
var my_xml = <element></element>;
```

I don't want to have the actual XML written in the document and would much rather it was in an external XML file which is then embedded during compilation, does anyone know if this is possible in Typescript?

I'd normally load the XML file from an external source, but for this project I need it all to be in the final js that the Typescript compiler produces.

I'm from an Actionscript background and used to use a special compile command to do this:

```
[Embed(source="test.xml", mimeType="text/xml")]
protected const EmbeddedXML:Class;
```

Which would pull in the file during compiling which could then be referred to by the constant underneath.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript doesn't have any native processing of that sort, but there are plenty of tools to do it for you.  [sed](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/worlds-best-introduction-to-sed/) is a well worn, trustworthy tool for string editing.

If you're using VisualStudio you'll have to [download sed for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm), go into the .csproj file, find the `<Target Name="AfterBuild">` and create an [exec task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx) that slips your xml in the generated js file.

If you're not on VisualStudio you're probably using Grunt, in which case there's a [grunt task](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-sed) that looks solid.

Comment: I'll add an example command soon that includes escaping the XML.

Comment: It turns out that the sed ```r``` command will insert the lines of a file after a token, but not replace it.  So that's not quite the right tool.  Probably running a js file with node or jscript would be easiest.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a grunt task that does exactly that : https://github.com/basarat/grunt-ts#html-2-typescript-support. It will take your html / xml file and create a TypeScript file that contains the contents of your html file as a variable.

Check it out in the video as well : http://youtu.be/0-6vT7xgE4Y?t=11m48s&hd=1

Answer (score 0):

The only format that you can require from node.js/TypeScript so its embedded in your code  is json. The only way so fay I found to solve this is at compile time with tool such as https://github.com/cancerberoSgx/fs-to-json